# GlassFish Load balancer configurator plugin installs 64-bit binaries on a 32-bit machine

Tags: glassfish

I'm running GlassFish 3.1.2.2 and iPlanet 7 on 32-bit Ubuntu 12.10
I'm installing GlassFish Load balancer configurator plugin v3.1.2.2.
Installation process goes OK and doesn't report any errors:

> INFO: Started installation of GlassFish Load Balancer Plugin
>   INFO: Detected Oracle iPlanet Web Server version as 7.x
>   INFO: Completed installation of GlassFish Load Balancer Plugin
>   INFO: GlassFish load-balancer plugin installation completed successfully.

But when I'm trying to start iPlanet instance it reports an error:

> ADMIN3603: Error while starting the server:
>   failure: CORE2253: Error running Init function load-modules: dlopen of .../webserver7/plugins/lbplugin/bin/libpassthrough.so failed (.../webserver7/plugins/lbplugin/bin/libpassthrough.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64)
>   failure: server initialization failed

I'm checking that libpassthrough.so with:

> file libpassthrough.so

and it reports that

> libpassthrough.so: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, stripped

Any ideas how can I make Load balancer plugin to install the 32-bit version of binaries?

Answer (score 0):

This is not related to the load balancer plugin anymore, starting from iPlanet 7 libpassthrough.so is bundled into the web server.

You need to download a linux 32 bits compatible installer from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/webtier/downloads/iplanet-webserver-525365.html in order to run it from a 32 bits machine.

Comment: There is no any traces of load balancer plugin in a fresh iPlanet 7 installation, like libpassthrough.so